# How to format string encoded with NSASCIIStringEncoding

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, cloudkit, nsstringencoding

In my Objective-C project, I'm fetching a key from cloudKit and wanted to format it before like this and wondering what's wrong with the formatting,

```
    [cloudKitDB performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray<CKRecord *> * _Nullable results, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[results.firstObject objectForKey:@"keyvalue"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"First Key Output: %@",key);
    NSLog(@"Second Key Output: %@",key);

    NSString *formattedKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[key stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]], @"1234"];
    NSLog(@"Formatted Key: %@",formattedKey);
```

And here my logged

```
2020-08-15 21:08:14.704650+0700 myapp[2208:79554] First Key Output: ADEvXp2F2BFJ2E4Lm2dSnYvHENhkFrK8
2020-08-15 21:08:14.704828+0700 myapp[2208:79554] Second Key Output: ADEvXp2F2BFJ2E4Lm2dSnYvHENhkFrK8
2020-08-15 21:08:14.705456+0700 myapp[2208:79554] Formatted Key: ADEvXp2F2BFJ2E4Lm2dSnYvHENhkFrK8
```

Although, I have tried to trim whitespace but still no luck!

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the ASCII encodig. I think there may be something appended to the key, such as a newline, that causes the 1234 to print on the next line. Can you perhaps paste in the full output and not just show it in the comments?

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong / unexpected about your "logged" output? It looks fine.

Comment: @matt The formatted key output should be ADEv...1234

Comment: Can you explain how to reproduce your results? I do get the "1234".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a strange problem, but I can reproduce it with the code below.

Based on this I still suspect that there are some funnies behind the string and have given ways to fix it in the code.

```
        // Note C strlen will stop at the first 0
        char     * s            = "3Lm9dGmeTf3Lm9dGmeTf3Lm9dGmeTfdd\0\0\0";
        NSData   * data         = [NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen( s ) + 2];
        NSString * key          = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString * keyFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", key, @"1234"];

        NSLog ( @"Key          : %@", key );
        NSLog ( @"Formatted key: %@", keyFormatted );

        // Use strlen to get rid of funnies
        NSData   * dataFixed = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange( 0, strlen( s ) )];
        NSString * keyFixed  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataFixed encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString * keyForm2  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", keyFixed, @"1234"];

        NSLog ( @"Fixed key    : %@", keyFixed );
        NSLog ( @"Formatted key: %@", keyForm2 );

        // Use C isprint to trim ... crude but works
        while ( key.length && ! isprint ( [key characterAtIndex:key.length - 1] ) )
        {
            key = [key substringToIndex:key.length - 1];
        }

        keyFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", key, @"1234"];

        NSLog ( @"Key          : %@", key );
        NSLog ( @"Formatted key: %@", keyFormatted );
```

Comment: I'm glad someone was able to reproduce it! Nice work.

Comment: matt!!! thanks - I suspect some comms stuff get left behind that data ... or maybe the encoding is incorrect ... but strange that you can trick the format to discard the last argument ...

Comment: @skaak I appreciate very much for your help and your solution is work!!!!